# Multi-colorful or multi-colored?

Tags: meaning, grammar, descriptive-grammar, style-manuals

Is multi-colorful a word? Or is the correct word multi-colored?

Comment: multi-colored is good. Can't imagine using multi-colorful.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/), the prefix *multi-* is defined as:

> *combining form*
>
> 1. many or much
> 2. more than one

Whereas *colorful* is defined as:

> *adjective*
>
> 1. full of color or of vivid colors
> 2. full of interest or variety; vivid

Additionally, it is worthwhile to note that *multicolored* is defined as:

> *adjective*
>
> having many colors

Thus, based on the above definitions, the "word" *multicolorful* does not appear like a proper word. However, *multicolored* is.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: 'Does not seem like a word' is not a good answer on ELU; does it appear in major dictionaries? Arguing from logic is based on the assumption that English always behaves in predictable ways. Which essentially requires that _people_ always behave in predictable ways.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, while that is noted (and Bayesian ;), could you bring an example to your claim?

Comment: I make 3 claims here.